# Need to implement Disaster Management for Marklogic Database

Tags: marklogic

I need to implement a disaster management system for Marklogic database. What will be the best way to do it? May be using Failover or Flexible replication. But i am not able to identify how this works on shared networks. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: This is too broad for this site I'm afraid. Do a bit of Googling. `marklogic disaster management` shows a host of results, e.g. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/concepts/backup-replication

Comment: You need to define what kind of disaster management you are required to have.  Are you looking for a Disaster Recovery (DR) plan, a Continuity of Operations (COOP) plan?  Are there SLAs or Requirements documents that dictate how long you can be down?  1 min, 5 mins, 1 day, etc.  What do you mean by 'shared networks'?  Once you have determined your requirements, it's much easier to figure out what architecture will fit your needs.  Whether it be forest replicas, shared disk failover, database replication or Flex Rep, there are lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

I think this page from the MarkLogic website would be a good starting point to clear up your thoughts:

http://www.marklogic.com/what-is-marklogic/features/high-availability-disaster-recovery/

There are links further down to additional resources that tell you how things work, and how you can configure them.

Note that HA/DR functionality requires licenses with appropriate options, and MarkLogic clusters with 3 nodes each at the very least.

HTH!